# How do I create a simple discussion forum in my Android app using java in android studio?

Tags: android

I am at entry level learning to develop mobile App with Android Studio. I have manage to create a simple user login App with backend server, now I want to implement simple discussion forum in my App for all users, the language I am using is Java.
I don't know where to begin.

kindly assist.

Comment: That's the very broad question. Could you be more specific as in what have you tried and where are you stuck.

Comment: Please be on topic you can use other tutorial sides which you can use this purpose. [Like this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much more but I think to follow these three steps maybe you create discussion forum:
Enter name of your app and choose app category and template design.
Add features and customize your app, create a forum app without coding.
Publish your app to your favorite store and then launch your app to the app store of your choice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31178842)